# how to prevent website loading to a specific section of the web page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

whenever I am entering my website it will automatically redirect on the section || div that my Client Portal is located. How can I remove that?

https://www.pedept.com.au/

I am using the open-source "PerfectGym/ClientPortal" here's the link: https://github.com/PerfectGym/ClientPortal.Embed

This is the code on my website so far. how I embedded it.

```
<div id="pg-client-portal"></div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iframe-resizer@latest/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@perfectgym/client-portal@latest/dist/ClientPortal.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        

  var ClientPortal = window.PerfectGym.ClientPortal;

  // element to which ClientPortal will be appended
  var clientPortalElement = document.getElementById('pg-client-portal');
  var options =  {
            url: "https://pedept.perfectgym.com.au/ClientPortal2/#/Classes/1/List",
            calendarPage: {
                hideBookingIfNotLogged: false
            },
            navigation: {
                hide: false
            },
            defaultState: PerfectGym.ClientPortal.State.Classes
        };

  var embededClientPortal = new ClientPortal(clientPortalElement, options);
</script>
```